# Authenticating a Google Cloud Function as a service account on other Google APIs

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have an HTTP-triggered function running on Google Cloud Functions, which uses `require('googleapis').sheets('v4')` to write data into a docs spreadsheet.

For local development I added an account via the [Service Accounts](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) section of their developer console. I downloaded the token file (dev-key.json below) and used it to authenticate my requests to the Sheets API as follows:

```
var API_ACCT = require("./dev-key.json");
let apiClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  API_ACCT.client_email, null, API_ACCT.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
);

exports.myFunc = function (req, res) {
  var newRows = extract_rows_from_my_client_app_request(req);
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth: apiClient,
    // ...
    resource: { values:newRows }
  }, function (e) {
    if (e) res.status(500).json({err:"Sheets API is unhappy"});
    else res.status(201).json({ok:true})
  });
};
```

After I shared my spreadsheet with my service account's "email address" e.g. `local-devserver@foobar-bazbuzz-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com` — it worked!

However, as I go to deploy this to the Google Cloud Functions service, I'm wondering if there's a better way to handle credentials? Can my code authenticate itself automatically without needing to bundle a JWT key file with the deployment?

I noticed that there is a `FUNCTION_IDENTITY=foobar-bazbuzz-123456@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` environment variable set when my function runs, but I do not know how to use this in the `auth` value to my googleapis call. The [code for `google.auth.getApplicationDefault`](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/search?q=FUNCTION_IDENTITY) does not use that.

Is it considered okay practice to upload a private JWT token along with my GCF code? Or should I somehow be using the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) for that? Or is there a built-in way that Cloud Functions already can authenticate themselves to other Google APIs?

Answer (score 4):

It's common to bundle credentials with a function deployment.  Just don't check them into your source control.  [Cloud Functions for Firebase samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) do this where needed.  For example, creating a signed URL from Cloud Storage requires admin credentials, and [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail) illustrates saving that credential to a file to be deployed with the functions.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if there's a better way to handle credentials? Can my
>   code authenticate itself automatically without needing to bundle a JWT
>   key file with the deployment?

Yes.  You can use '[Application Default Credentials](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#application-default-credentials)', instead of how you've done it, but you don't use the function getApplicationDefault() as it has been deprecated since this Q was posted.

The link above shows how to make a simple call using the google.auth.getClient API, providing the desired scope, and have it decide the credential type needed automatically.  On cloud functions this will be a 'Compute' object, as defined in the google-auth-library.

These docs say it well [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_credentials_on_compute_engine_kubernetes_engine_app_engine_flexible_environment_and_cloud_functions)...

> After you set up a service account, ADC can implicitly find your
>   credentials without any need to change your code, as described in the
>   section above.

Where ADC is Application Default Credentials.

Note that, for Cloud Functions, you use the App Engine service account:
YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com, as [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity).  That is the one you found via the FUNCTION_IDENTITY env var - this rather tripped me up.

The final step is to make sure that the service account has the required access as you did with your spreadsheet.